# Restrict "Authority Section" on BIND

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, query, bind

I just switched from Microsoft DNS to BIND 9.3 for a DNS acting as a Caching Nameserver.

Previously when I used "dig" to perform a lookup...I just got the "QUESTION" & "ANSWER SECTION" with Microsoft DNS.  Now I receive (with BIND) an "AUTHORITY SECTION" (pointing to the nameservers of the domain I'm querying) all the time.

Is there an option in named.conf that could control this behaviour? I don't want to provide the "AUTHORITY" to the clients.

Comment: just out of interest, why do you want this?  The stub resolver in the clients will ignore the referrals in the authoritative section anyway.

Comment: Hi,
Check this: http://tinyurl.com/cf57me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out **minimal-responses** in the *options* statement.  That looks like it will do what you want.  The docs say:

> **minimal-responses**
>
> If **yes**, then when generating responses the server will only add records to the authority and additional data sections when they are required (e.g. delegations, negative responses). This may improve the performance of the server. The default is **no**.

Comment: Thanks Jeff!  It worked!  Exactly what I needed!  
All the best,JFA.